# IF Else statement not properly worked in setInterval() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setinterval

I have a problem with accessing if else, if else can called but both block called if block as well as else block at a same time

so how can i make proper working if else block

my code is

```
const UserCard=(props)=>{


const[LiveOrdStatus,setStatus] = useState();
const[order_ID,setordid] = useState(props.orderId);

const labels=["Order","Confirm","Ready","Deliver","Delivred"];
let number = 0;

function LiveFetchData(){
   fetch('https://example.in/app/live_update.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'S_KEY':'84014',
        'order_id':order_ID,
      })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      setStatus(json.order_status);
      //console.log(json.order_status);
    }).catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
}

LiveFetchData();
   setInterval(() => {
        if(LiveOrdStatus==="DELIVERED")
        {
         console.log("its okk :"+LiveOrdStatus);
        }else{
         console.log("not called :");
        }
  }, 10000);

 }
```

my output is
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are calling and setting an interval each render cycle and from what I can tell you never clear any intervals. You likely only want to start one interval when the component mounts. Don't forget to return a cleanup function to clear any running intervals when the component unmounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timerRef = setInterval(() => {
    if (LiveOrdStatus === "DELIVERED") {
      console.log("its okk :", LiveOrdStatus);
    } else {
      console.log("not called :");
    }
  }, 10000);

  return () => clearInterval(timerRef);
}, []);
```

You are also calling `LiveFetchData();` directly in the function body, which will cause render looping since it also updates state. I'm not sure when you want this function to be called, but it's likely that you also want to place it into an `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => LiveFetchData(), []);
```

This will invoke it once when the component mounts, but if you need to call it more often then you should figure out what any dependencies are or add additional interval timers, etc...

#### Update

> I am facing one more problem , when accessing `LiveOrdStatus` inside
> else than it show " not called : undefined "

Yeah, I see how that can happen now. Basically the initial `LiveOrdStatus` is closed over in the `setInterval` callback scope.

Use a React ref to cache the current `LiveOrdStatus` state value and access that in the interval.

```
    const LiveOrdStatusRef = React.useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
      LiveOrdStatusRef.current = LiveOrdStatus;
    }, [LiveOrdStatus]);

    useEffect(() => {
      const timerRef = setInterval(() => {
        if (LiveOrdStatus === "DELIVERED") {
          console.log("its okk :", LiveOrdStatusRef.current);
        } else {
          console.log("not called :", LiveOrdStatusRef.current);
        }
      }, 10000);

      return () => clearInterval(timerRef);
    }, []);
```

Comment: thank you soo much, my i understand and my problem was solver, thanks man for sav my time :)

Comment: sir i am facing one more problem , when accessing  LiveOrdStatus inside else than it show  " not called : undefined "

Comment: @JenilChavda Oh, yeah, totally see that now, sorry about that. Added an update to my answer. Please check it.

Comment: thank you sir, now all problems was solved and my program was perfectly worked :)

Answer (score 0):

you should call the function which are causing side effect in useEffect hook.

```
   const LiveFetchData = () => {

     fetch('https://example.in/app/live_update.php', {
     method: 'POST',
     mode: 'no-cors',
     headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({
     'S_KEY':'84014',
     'order_id':order_ID,
    })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
    setStatus(json.order_status);
    //console.log(json.order_status);
    }).catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
   }
  
   useEffect(() => {
      LiveFetchData();
    } , [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerRef = setInterval(() => {

    if (LiveOrdStatus==="DELIVERED") {
      console.log("its okk :"+LiveOrdStatus);
    } else {
      console.log("not called :");
    }
   }, 10000);

   return () => clearInterval(timerRef);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you're fetching `LiveFetchData()`, one time only when the `userCard` Component mounts. So you can wrap call it inside the `useEffect()`

```
useEffect(()=>{
 LiveFetchData(); // it will populate the status first
},[])
```

Then you can call setInterval normally to check the status.